# Prove addition formula for conditional probability

Tags: probability, statistics

Given $P(A) > 0$ and $B, C, D, \dots$ are mutually disjoint, prove that $P(B \cup C \cup D \cup \dots|A)=P(B|A)+P(C|A)+P(D|A)+\dots$

I don't really know where to start. I know that $P(B \cup C \cup D \cup \dots)=P(B)+P(C) + \dots$ for mutually exclusive events, but I'm not sure how to add the condition into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint

Just use that

$$(B\cup C\cup \cdots)\cap A=(B\cap A)\cup(C\cap A)\cup\cdots$$
and that if $B_1,B_2,\cdots$ are mutually disjoint then

$$P(B_1\cup B_2\cup\cdots)=P(B_1)+P(B_2)+\cdots$$
and of course the definition of the conditional probability.